# Haskell data constructor with some sort of function header issue?

Tags: haskell

Currently I have faced the following code that I have no idea on how this data constructor works. The code snippet is as follow:

```
data Parser a b = P {
  runParser :: Stream a -> [(b, Stream a)]
}
```

I understand that Haskell can have something called recorded syntax, but for this one, that is a bit blow my mind up.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What part specifically are you having problems understanding? There's a lot going on here, and an overview of it all would be too broad. Have you looked how records work?

Comment: @Carcigenicate  Stream a -> [(b, Stream a)] 
is this means if I type `:t runParser` in ghci, I will got `Parser a b -> Stream a -> [(b,Stream a)]` ???

Comment: Did you try that to see? And `Stream a -> [(b, Stream a)]` is a function that takes a Stream, and returns a list of tuples where the first element is of type b, and the second is a Stream of a's.

Comment: The record syntax does not change anything. In functional programming: functions are "*first class citizens*". You can pass them as arguments, return them as a result, and store them in a constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well basically this is just regular record synax:

```
data Parser a b = P {
  runParser :: Stream a -> [(b, Stream a)]
}
```

It means that the `Parser a b` data type has *one* data constructor. A data constructor named `P`, and that constructor has *one* argument: a "field" called `runParser`, and that field has type `Stream a -> [(b, Stream a)]`.

This pattern is quite common in Haskell and in functional programming in general. Functions are "*first class citizens*". It means that functions can be passed as arguments, a function can return another function (in fact due to currying this happens very often in Haskell), and we can store (references to) function in a data constructor.

We can for example create a `Parser Int Char` type with:

```
P (\_ -> []) :: Parser Int Char
```

So here we constructed a `Parser Int Char` and the argument, a single function, maps any value to an empty list.

Or another example:

```
P (\x -> [('a', x), ('b', x)]) :: Parser Int Char
```

Here we thus map our `Stream a` object `x`, to a list of 2-tuples, one with `'a'` as first element, and one with `'b'` as first element. Each time we pick `x` as second element.

Or we can define a function, and pass a reference to that function:

```
f :: Stream Int -> [(Char, Stream Int)]
f x = [('a', x)]

P f :: Parser Int Char
```

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look on that :)